# get elements positions of a vector with minimal distance from a certain pattern

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Having a vector of strings **strvec** and a **pattern string** , I try to do a fuzzy search along strvec to get all elements positions with minimal distance from pattern + certain tolerance (tol). geometrically speaking I want t get the words in the circle that have radius equal to : minimal distance from strvec+tol. So my algorithm should get :

- element position with minimal_distance from strvec (in case strvec contain pattern , algorithm should continue to search to get minimal distance that is different of zero.

  - all element positions where **distance < minimal_distance  +tol**

I assume that the distance is computed using a function **get_distance**.

Here my code:

```
vector<int> dist_minimal(const char* pattern, vector<string> strvec,int tol=4)
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  int min = 100; //  big value to init
  for (vector<string>::iterator it = strvec.begin(); it != strvec.end() ; it++){
   int lev_dist=get_distance(pattern, *it);
   auto position = it-strvec.begin()+1 ;
   if(lev_dist < min && lev_dist >0){
     v.clear();
     v.push_back(position);
     min = lev_dist;
     std::cout << min << std::endl;
   }else if (lev_dist == min){
     v.push_back(position);
   }
  }
  return v;
}
```

I only get elements with exactly equal to minimal distance no those between min_distance and min_distance+tol.

Comment: Small surprise, given that you never use `tol` in your code. If you don't know your minimum distance beforehand, you must either find it first with an additional loop or keep track of the distances associated with the elements in `v` and discard elements when a new minimum is found. (It is probably easier to make `tol` an absolute tolerance, which means that `v` might be empty.)

Comment: @MOehm how would you do this in c++?

Comment: Split your code into two subsequent loops. First find the min value, i.e. use your code without pushing to `v`. Next, loop again and push all distances that are within `min + tol` to your result vector `v`. Note: You should probably calculate the distances only once and store them in a temporary vector. You should probably also return the zero-based index in the code, so better don't add one to your position. And note that your function loses the information what the minimum distance actually is. (The results are virtually worthless if the min distance is, say, more than ten.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

```
else if (lev_dist == min)
{
    v.push_back(position);
}
```

To

```
else if ((lev_dist <= (min + tol)) && (lev_dist >= (min - tol)))
{
    v.push_back(position);
}
```